# Form processing using two php scripts one after another

Tags: php, forms, post, processing

I have a page with a form for logging to a sub section in my website "login.php". I want to do some logging of the user information. Like Username, time, browser used... but without touching to the original 'login.php' with a certain transparency to the user, the pass the form to the original script for setting cookies...

I was thinking adding a second page 'login.html' containing the form with `action=logtofile.php` then pass the data to the original 'login.php' that allows the user accessing to the members area.

Answer (score 0):

Try being more specific, I've no idea what is your problem. Also there should be at least one question mark in a question :)

I don't see why you need two PHP scripts, why can't you write both logging user information and perform user login into one script?

Comment: I can't because the original "login.php" is constantly modified by a friend who is working on the web site, So I wanted to log the data without messing the origial script.